# Script stops when sending strings including newline from perl/cgi to client using json

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, perl

I use Perl/cgi to recieve content from mysql and then pass it to client using json
But, it all stops up while passing string containing newlines to client.

The string are submitted from a textarea and written to a mysql db.
That part works out nice, saving the string correctly, and also writes it out correctly in php.
But then it all stops, looks like the string breaks up in several lines in the json part, and breaks the code.

I have validated my json-string.

Anyone out there with a smooth solution?

Here are part of the code i´m using i perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;
binmode( STDOUT, ":utf8" );    #denne gjør det mulig å sende æ ø å uten feil
binmode(STDIN);
require Encode;

#print out result:
print '[{"prosjekter":[';
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $file_no; $i++ ) {
    print '{"prosjektId":'
        . $prosjekter[$i]{"id"}
        . ',"prosjektNavn":"'
        . $prosjekter[$i]{"prosjektNavn"}
        . '","prosjektNummer":"'
        . $prosjekter[$i]{"prosjektNummer"}
        . '","info":"'
        . $prosjekter[$i]{"info"}
        . '","bulk":"'
        . $prosjekter[$i]{"bulk"} . '"}';
    if ( $i < ( $file_no - 1 ) ) {
        print ',';
    }
}
print ']}]';
```

This is the script receiving json result from server:

```
    var string = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        var sale = string[i];
        var ac=1;
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var prosjekt = sale.prosjekter;
        for(var pi = 0; pi < sale.prosjekter.length; pi++){
            var prosjektId = prosjekt[pi].prosjektId;
            var prosjektNummer = prosjekt[pi].prosjektNummer;
            var prosjektNavn = prosjekt[pi].prosjektNavn;       
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO PROSJEKTER (id, prosjektNummer, prosjektNavn) VALUES ('+prosjektId+', "'+prosjektNummer+'", "'+prosjektNavn+'")');
            //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML+='<br>INSERT INTO KUNDER_TIL_PROSJEKTER (kundeId, prosjektId) VALUES ('+kundeId+', '+prosjektId+')';

            ac++;
            if(ac == sale.prosjekter.length) alert("Prosjekter oppdatert!");
        }   
        //alert(kortNavn);
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module?

Comment: That was a new place for me. I will take a really good look into that. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

There is more to the spec for JSON then just stringifying the key/value pairs.  Therefore use a module that will handle everything for you, such as taking care of strings that contain newlines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %hash = (
    number => 17,
    word => "banana",
    paragraph => "Hello world\nWhat's up world?\nGoodbye world.",
);

print to_json \%hash;
```

Outputs:

```
{"word":"banana","number":17,"paragraph":"Hello world\nWhat's up world?\nGoodbye world."}
```